# How do I know if the diode is conducting or not?

Tags: amplifier, diodes

I want to design a precision rectifier with the circuit below by choosing proper R1, R2 and R3.

I'm trying to analyze the question by considering Vi>0 and Vi<0.

How can I know if D1 or D2 is conducting?

[image]

For example, I don't see a problem when D1 and D2 are both on when Vi>0, but in the answer my teacher provided, the Vi>0 case would only cause D1 on and make D2 off.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the two cases- Vi < 0 and Vi > 0. Assume for the moment that the op-amp inputs are at 0V in each case. That's not true for all circuits of this type, but let's assume that for now and see if it makes sense.

Case 1: Vi < 0

The inverting op-amp terminal is at 0V for the op-amp to balance. The output is >0V and therefore D1 is off and D2 is on. It acts like an inverting amplifier with gain determined by R1 and R2, and R3 has no effect.

Case 2: Vi > 0

The inverting op-amp terminal is at 0V (assumed) so current is flowing through D1 to make that happen. The op-amp output will be at about -0.7V for a silicon diode. Vo will be >0 so D1 is off. In this case the op-amp is not involved in the circuit output (other than to maintain a virtual ground) and we have a voltage divider composed of R3 and R2 (the latter connected to the virtual ground at the op-amp inverting input).

Answer (score 0):

> how can I know if D1 or D2 is conducting?

When the voltage at the anode of a diode is higher than the voltage at its cathode, the diode is conducting.

When the voltage at the anode of a diode is lower than the voltage at its cathode, the diode is not conducting.